# force gpg to use a particular certificate

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption, gnupg

I'm using gpg4win and i have 3 keys / certificates that i created.
I'm trying to encrypt a file using the most recent certificate i created using a bat file that runs before the connection.
Using this code, it loops through all the files in a folder and signs / encrypts them using a passphrase stored in another file:

`for /R ".\Input\" %%i in (*) do gpg.exe  --pinentry-mode=loopback --batch --sign --passphrase %ENPWD% "%%~i"`

**When i run it thou it keeps telling me that my passphrase is incorrect as it tries to use the default key(?)**

I'm also planning to create more keys, one for each provider we connect to and send files to.
Bizarrely the same code works correctly in another instance using the second certificate.
I can encrypt fine using the kleopatra gui specifying the correct key.

What am i doing wrong? Can i force gpg to use a particular certificate in a command line such as the above?

thank you for your help

Comment: This is a total guess as im not familiar with gpg (I was just editing the post), it looks like you are missing a "=" between "passphrase" and "%ENPWD%"

Comment: that part is ok, i believe. it works fine on the other 2 instances.

Comment: ok. it is now resolved

here's the final code

for /R ".\Input\" %%i in (*) do gpg.exe  --pinentry-mode=loopback --batch --default-key <KEYNAME> --sign --passphrase %ENPWD% "%%~i"

Comment: Please post it as an answer so other people that encounter the same issue may find it :)

Answer (score 0):

ok. it is now resolved here's the final code for /R ".\Input" %%i in (*) do gpg.exe --pinentry-mode=loopback --batch --default-key  --sign --passphrase %ENPWD% "%%~i"